# ¿Cómo sería la cardinalidad de juegos-plataforma?

Tags: base-de-datos, modelorelacional, diagrama-er

Es decir, aunque muchos juegos sean de varias plataformas, físicamente un juego solo puede ir en una plataforma aunque, luego existan otras copias del mismo juego hechas para otras plataformas. Por ejemplo, a la hora de crear una base de datos, donde cada juego (aunque sea el mismo) tendrá su precio según la plataforma a la que pertenezca.

¿Sería de uno a muchos o seguiría siendo de muchos a muchos?

Comment: Esto depende de la información que quieras guardar en cada objeto. Puedes hacer un objeto intermedio donde guardas la información del Juego, la de la Plataforma y el precio correspondiente. Es decir, una relación n a m.

Comment: @Wyrncael y si toda esa información excepto el de la plataforma, se guardara en la tabla juego. ¿Cómo quedaría?

Comment: `físicamente un juego solo puede ir en una plataforma aunque, luego existan otras copias del mismo juego` En muchos modelos, la costumbre de usar la misma palabra para distintos conceptos es la causa de muchísimos errores. Tu "juego" y las "copias del juego" parecen ser conceptos distintos.

Comment: @SJuan76 nunca lo había visto de esa forma. Es decir, que mientras una entidad sea de muchos da igual como lo mires, seguira siendo de muchos ¿no?

Comment: No, para nada. Lo que digo es que estás confundiendo el concepto de "título" (p.ej *Halo*) con el de "versión" (*Halo para Steam*), y poniéndolo todo junto porque todo tiene el nombre "juego".

Answer (score 1):

Te pongo un diagrama para explicar un poco mejor lo que estoy comentandote.

Las 'cajas' son las tablas de la base de datos, las relaciones son 1-N con la entidad de 'Juego y Plataforma' y en azul te pongo un ejemplo de los datos que irían en cada tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lógicamente faltarían ids u otros campos que necesites utilizar.

Comment: Ostras! Gracias por las molestias. La verdad es que así lo he entendido bien. Gracias de nuevo.